# How to add multiple points into a chart with "AddY(Object[])" method in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

We are developing WPF C# application with Visual Studio 2019.
It has a chart which displays 300 line * 10000 points all at once.
Of course the data is really large, the update is very slow. Let's me show our example code.

```
private System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

~~~Abbreviated~~~~~~~

sw.Start();
for(int i=0;i<300;i++){
chart1.Series[i].Points.DataBindY(my1Darray)
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

My stopwatch returned over 8000msec... We concluded DataBind method didn't satisfy our requirements.

As next idea, we tried to use [AddY(Object[]) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection.addy?view=netframework-4.8).

```
object[] myObject = new object[1];

for(int i=0; i<300;i++){
   myObject[i] = "42";  //Assign user-defined value   
   chart1.Series[i].Points.AddY(myobject[0]);
}
```

It worked fine. 
[image: Result]

But when we made a small modification like this,

```
 object[] myObject = new object[1];

for(int i=0; i<300;i++){
   myObject[i] = "1,2";  //Assign user-defined value   
   chart1.Series[i].Points.AddY(myobject[0]);
}
```

Very strange... the line was on "12". I hoped the line was ...2,1,2,1,2,1
[image]

We also made another modification like this,

```
object[] myObject = new object[2];

for(int i=0; i<300;i++){
   myObject[0] = "56";  //Assign user-defined value
   myObject[1] = "67";
   chart1.Series[i].Points.AddY(myobject);
}
```

An error said "You can set only yValue-1point to this Datapoint (parameter name: yValue)".

We are in over head!! We'd like to add multiple points all at once but couldn't...
Does anyone have a good solution? It would be helpful sharing an example which uses AddY(Object[]) method.

Comment: Have you looked at `DataBindXY`?  Or perhaps use multi threading to create the lines in parallel and display them asynchronously? It would be helpful to know what the source of the data is as I assume you are not just creating random points in a loop and displaying them.

Comment: Hi Barns, I'm really surprised your quick response!! Yes, we have already checked DataBindXY but it also requires much update time. My data source is 1D array, not DataSet and Datatable type. My reference is this YouTube tutorial. 

c# "REAL" Time Charts Tutorial - YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHyKfCn3zzM

Comment: What is `chart1` in your example? You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).